# sql update query with space separated column name

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Update Student Set First Name='adwd' Where StudentID=123;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

This query is not working in mysql , because the column name in my table is space separated. if i do the query on another column which is not comma separated it will work.

However ,i want to keep the first name as is. I tried using [] and `` and "" and '' none of them have worked. Is this just impossible to do and i have to rename my column names ?

I hope some1 can provide a good solution

thx community :)

Comment: what is adwd? if it is a literal string, you should enclose it in quotes

Comment: its a string, ok i enclosed it but it still failed:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this**

```
Update Student Set `First Name`='adwd' Where StudentID=123;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL, the correct syntax is:

```
Update Student
    Set `First Name` = 'adwd'
    Where StudentID = 123;
```

If this doesn't work, then something else is wrong with the query apart from the column name.  Note that backticks are used for escaping the column name in MySQL.

Comment: thank you gordon, i accepted esi's answer because it was quicker. by a few seconds. but a big thx for u both , back to work :)